# Is it possible for libcurl to return a CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK by itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, curl, libcurl

```cpp
CURLCode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

If we don't return a non-zero value on curl callback, for example `CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION` always return zero, and is the `curl_easy_perform` call possible return `CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK` from internal?

Answer (score 0):

No, if that ever happens it is probably a bug.